# how can we get category by name and parant category id?

Tags: magento-1.8, category, collection

How can I check category have any child category with specific name ?

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($name, 'name');
```

but I want sub category from specific parent category.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try using category collection

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
              ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',$parent_id)
              ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array(
              'like' => '%amit%'
             ));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try This Code.

```
$category_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$_category = $category_model->load(13);
$all_child_categories = $category_model->getResource()->getAllChildren($_category);
print_r($all_child_categories);
```

Answer (score 0):

here 149 is Category id you can replace with your own

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category'); 

    $category->load(149); 
    $childrenString = $category->getChildren(); 
    $children = explode(',',$childrenString);
```